# Boot time scan of Avast: "XXX archive is corrupt"

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I scanned my PC using the "boot-time scan" of Avast because I wanted to detect if there is a virus on my system.

I didn't find any viruses after the scan but it did detect some archives that are corrupt inside Windows folders, and some of my installers that I haven't found using an Avast "full system scan". To be specific there are three letters before "archive is corrupt" like "CDO archive is corrupt" or something similar.

Is this bad? Will this affect my computer? Is it some kind of virus only detected with a boot-time scan?

Comment: What version of Avast?

Comment: 6.0.1203 is the version of the avast i use

Comment: It realy deepens which files are corrupt.  if they are essential, then yes it really does matter, if not, then not.  Please provide more details.

Comment: @wizlog that is the best detail i can provide, anyways what does archieve is corrupt means?

Comment: Data corruption refers to errors in computer data that occur during writing, reading, storage, transmission, or processing, which introduce unintended changes to the original data.

Check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_corruption) Wikipedia article.

Comment: im not affected by 20 corrupt archives now. why is that?

Comment: Because they must be non-essential to operating system's operations (running).

Comment: maybe these corrupted files are from the hibernate mode which i canceled,

Comment: Please just read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which files are currupt, I'd run "CHKDSK C: /f" this can be done through the command prompt which can be run by typing "CMD" into the search bar of the start menu.

This is assuming you can boot your computer.  If not, you can still run the command prompt through the [**Startup Repair**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Startup-Repair-frequently-asked-questions), or through [**safe mode**](HTTP://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode)

## Here is what the command actually means when broken down.

- **CHKDSK** Is the command for Check Disk
- **C:**  Specifies the drive letter (**followed by a *colon***),
- **/F**             Fixes errors on the disk.
- **/R**              Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information
                (implies **/F** and is therefore optional).

For a more complete list of what CHKDSK can do, type "**chkdsk /?**" into the command prompt window.

It wouldn't be a bad Idea in the future to backup your data regularly just in-case something went wrong.
**DON't forget to "Run as administrator" privileges**

**DON'T FORGET TO PRESS ENTER TO EXECUTE THE COMMAND**

Comment: i typed that on my command prompt and it replies "access denied as you do not have sufficient privilages. you have to invoke this utility running in elevated mode."

Comment: will this detect all corrupt data etc from the disk? will this help me solve the problem? to purify the corrupt archives?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that you need to run with administrative privileges. Just right click the Command Prompt before you (left click to) open, and click "Run as administrator", then click allow to the box that pops up.

Comment: this does not work, i tried this and it didnt even detected the corrupted archieves

Comment: then they aren't system critical

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you mean CRC? Archives might be corrupted in transfer-time. But there is quite high probability that your hard drive is approaching its end of life. I would recommend checking SMART statistics/read speeds of the disk. If you find anything suspicious - buy another disk as fast as possible

Comment: my hard disk might fail? i just bought my laptop 5months ago.

Comment: One of my hard disks failed after 2 or 3 months of usage ;] Hard drives usually fail in their first years or after 3-5.
If it's a laptop there's high probability that you just managed to damage a very tiny portion of surface. Just bear in mind that you should track this issue for a month or a bit more. If there are more files damaged - warranty service. chkdsk /F /R should hide this issue (damaged archives won't be repaired though)

Comment: im not affected now by the corrupt archive , so that means the corrupt archives are minor? will this affect my pcs performance in the future?

Comment: Can't tell without inspection of the disk itself. IF the disk is failing - yes, performance will drop and eventually all data will become inaccessible. IF it is one time issue - forget it. As I've said - bear in mind that this MIGHT become an issue in about 1 or 2 months